# Null Checking of a model property in JS within a Razor View

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, null-check

My model property MobileNumber may have a value or may be null. I am trying to check for this within my View, using JS.

```
var mobileNumber =  @String.IsNullOrEmpty((Model.MobileNumber));
```

However the browser console doesn't like this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: True is not defined

It looks like its trying to assign True to the variable mobileNumber:

```
var mobileNumber =  True;
```

Any idea why this is not working? I  can't do checks such as:

`if (@Model.MobileNumber == null)` because this ends up as `if(  == null)`.

when  the value is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet:

```
 var mobileNumber =  @(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.MobileNumber) ? "true" : "false");
```

We are trying to assign True to variable `mobilenumber` in javascript. Without quotes, javascript will try to interpret TRUE as a value/expression. There is no value TRUE natively defined in javascript. It is "true" but javascript is case sensitive so it won't bind "TRUE" to true.